# Можно ли в C# у Enum переходить к следующему значению покругу?

Tags: c#, enum

Я решил написать шахматы. У меня есть поле **move** обозначающее чей сейчас ход.

```
public class Chess
{
    ColorPiece move;
    ...
}

public enum ColorPiece
{
    White,
    Black
}
```

Я думал что можно просто инкрементом **move++**(ибо компилятор не жалуется) чтоб "переключать" но оказалось так он выходит за границы.
Есть ли возможность это исправить?

P.S. знаю что можно по другому но интересно просто.

Comment: Попробовать так public enum ColorPiece{....,End} и move = (move+1) % ColorPiece.End

Comment: move = (ColorPiece)((int)(move + 1) % (int)ColorPiece.END) только так ибо неявно преобразовывать из int в enum не хочет. но выглядит так себе хоть и работает как надо

Comment: e = e == Enum.END ? Enum.START : e++; можно и так кстати

Comment: Ну и у Вас вариант с "++" - тоже ну ахти:) enum не для этого.

Comment: `move = move == ColorPiece.White ? ColorPiece.Black : ColorPiece.White;` А если в перечислении больше двух значений, то вместо тернарки использовать `if - else`.

Comment: я так в проге своей и написал но если бы у меня enum был не из двух элементов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для частного случая типа

```
enum Power 
{
    On = 0,
    Off = 1
}
```

Можно сделать просто

```
static Power Switch(Power value)
{
    return value ^ Power.Off;
}
```

Проверяем

```
Power power = Power.On;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(power);
    power = Switch(power);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
On
Off
On
Off
On
Off
On
Off
On
Off
```

---

Для более общего случая, когда неизвестно количество элементов перечисления, их значения или даже тип перечисления, можно написать такой метод

```
static T Next<T>(T value) where T : struct, Enum
{
    T[] values = Enum.GetValues<T>();
    int index = (Array.IndexOf(values, value) + 1) % values.Length;
    return values[index];
}
```

Проверяем

```
enum DayOfWeek
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dayOfWeek);
    dayOfWeek = Next(dayOfWeek);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

Answer (score 1):

Аккумулирую.
Правильный ответ в случае если enum из двух элементов:

```
enum Enum
{
   Start,
   End
}
var e = Enum.Start;
e ^= Enum.End;
```

В случае если больше то нашёл только `e = e == Enum.END ? Enum.START : e++;`

Answer (score -1):

Идея такая:

```
move ^= 1;
```

Но на C# это не скомпилируется - придётся добавить значение в сам енум:

```
public enum ColorPiece
{
    White = 0,
    Black = 1,
    Xor = 1,
}

move ^= ColorPiece.Xor;
```

Добавляю отдельным значением, чтобы не было привязки к тому, кто там 0, а кто - 1.

Comment: я сейчас проверил и получается можно просто `move ^= ColorPiece.Black;` и если чередовать то будет от начального на указанный прыгать и обратно т.е. 
`Emun AZ{a, ..., d, ... z, } e = AZ.d; e ^= AZ.z` будет с d на z прыгать. т.к. у меня enum из двух значений то это мне и нужно. спасибо

Comment: А если в enum больше 2 значений? Какой XOR?

Comment: `e = e == Enum.END ? Enum.START : e++` только так наверное

Comment: @aepot, с правкой не согласен. Переписал по-другому.

Comment: @Uucyc, можно, но мне эта идея не нравится.

Comment: @Виктор, но в вопросе ведь только 2. Если бы была другая степень двойки, можно было бы упорядочить значения [кодом Грея](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/gray_code), хотя, вряд ли это имеет смысл.